# Mysql Config Optimization Suggestion

Tags: php, mysql, centos

I have server with 8 GB RAM and 8 Core, Running one website, I have done mysql configuration setting, on which server working normally, but in some times (1 to 2  times in 24 hours), it takes so much load. Os running CentOS

Need suggestion.

```
[mysqld]
connection settings
max_connect_errors=10
max_connections=500
max_user_connections=700
wait_timeout=60
connect_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=60
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6GB

cache settings
query_cache_limit=128M
query_cache_size=10M
query_cache_type=1
table_open_cache=5000
thread_cache_size=250

buffer sizes
key_buffer=1288M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer_size=20M
join_buffer_size=20M


tmpdir / temp table sizes
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M

misc. settings
default-storage-engine = MYISAM
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
skip-external-locking

server-id = 1
open-files-limit = 96384
max_allowed_packet = 300M

innodb settings
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency = 10
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1000M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 500M
innodb_file_per_table = 1

[mysqld_safe]
open-files-limit = 16384

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=600M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 128M
sort_buffer = 128M
read_buffer = 128M
write_buffer = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
```

Comment: even your default engine is myisam but configuration seems for innodb, what kind of tables you are using either myisam, innodb or mix...if mix what is percentage and reason to keep them myisam or innodb.

Comment: I am using  innodb not myisam store engine.

Comment: Do you even know what causes the load? You just dumped config variables without proper information about what exactly causes the load spike and why. You can configure your MySQL to infinity and beyond if you have no idea why the load happens. You're trying to cure a disease that you don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you have assigned more RAM to mysql than you have physically on server. Please check my comment below against variables-

```
    [mysqld]

    #connection setting
    max_connect_errors=10
    max_connections=500 #each connection consumes server resources, so keep how many required.
    max_user_connections=700 #It should be always less than max_connections,even you should remove it.
    wait_timeout=60
    connect_timeout=10
    interactive_timeout=60
    innodb_buffer_pool_size=6GB #duplicate as already mentioned below

    #cache setting
    query_cache_limit=128M #this should be less than query_cache_size, 2M will be sufficient we should not cache heavy queries as it will slow the process.
    query_cache_size=10M #can keep 20M or increase as per requirement.
    query_cache_type=1
    table_open_cache=5000
    thread_cache_size=250 --even not impact much to performance but still should not more than 100.

    #buffer sizes
    key_buffer=1288M # keep it 20M as your server is innodb
    sort_buffer_size=20M #this variable consumes server resources for each connection, 2M should be sufficient but can increase based on your queries.
    read_buffer_size=20M #this variable consumes server resources for each connection, 2M should be sufficient but can increase based on your queries.
    join_buffer_size=20M #this variable consumes server resources for each connection, 2M should be sufficient but can increase based on your queries.

    #tmpdir / temp table sizes
    tmp_table_size=256M
    max_heap_table_size=256M

    #misc. settings
    default-storage-engine = MYISAM # change to innoDB
    datadir=/var/lib/mysql
    skip-external-locking

    server-id = 1
    open-files-limit = 96384
    max_allowed_packet = 300M # You can reduce it to 64M or how much really required, fine if your application is sending large packet. 

    #innodb settings
    innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
    innodb_thread_concurrency = 0 #mysql can utilize it better read this > http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1000M # It should be how much you can increase in innodb upto 80% of RAM.
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 500M #8M is fine can increase as per server write in your environment but not 500M, as consumes server resources based on no of connections.
    innodb_file_per_table = 1

    [mysqld_safe]
    log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log

    [mysqldump]
    quick
```

Note: You can leave other sections except [mysqld], [mysqld_Safe] nd [mysqldump]

Finally you can test your server with below configuration-

```
[mysqld]

#connection setting
max_connect_errors=10
max_connections=400
wait_timeout=60
connect_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=60

#cache setting
query_cache_limit=2M
query_cache_size=50M
query_cache_type=1
table_open_cache=5000
thread_cache_size=100

#buffer sizes
key_buffer_size=20M
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=2M
join_buffer_size=2M

#tmpdir / temp table sizes
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M

#misc. settings
default-storage-engine = innoDB
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
skip-external-locking

server-id = 1
open-files-limit = 65535
max_allowed_packet = 64M 

#innodb settings
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M 
innodb_file_per_table = 1

[mysqldump]
quick
```

Note: If you can reduce total_connections then you can increase innodb_buffer_pool_size and can get better performance. with 250 users you can increase innodb_buffer_pool_size from 4GB to 5GB.

Still first you need to test your server and can +/- as per requirement/performance.

Comment: along with your server configuration correction, you need to look into your server slowlogs and try to optimize problematic queries.

Comment: I have added this in server mysql config file, now load average is decreasing.  Thanks :)